# In Bokeh, can the CustomJS code use data from the Hovertool?

Tags: python, charts, bokeh

What I am trying to do is the following: given some (x,y) coordinates, plot a graph. When a point on that graph is clicked/hovered over, look up some other set of coordinates, (i,j) (these coordinates will be indexed/a function of the (x,y) coordinates), and plot those coordinates (i,j) on a second graph next to the first.

I am able to do everything I mentioned using Bokeh, other than the fact that while using CustomJS, I am using the Tap event, which does not give coordinates of the actual point, rather it'll give a close approximation to the actual point since it just looks at the mouse coordinates. I don't see any event that will fit this purpose. I saw that the Hovertool actually is able to indicate specific points. Is it possible for me to use that Hoverdata instead? I can't figure out how to incorporate the two or if there is another way.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HoverTool.callback`, here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column

source1 = ColumnDataSource(data={"freq":np.random.uniform(2, 10, 10), "amp":np.random.uniform(-2, 2, 10)})
source2 = ColumnDataSource(data={"x":np.linspace(-5, 5, 200), "y":np.zeros(200)})

fig1 = figure(plot_height=200)
fig2 = figure(plot_height=200)
circle = fig1.circle("freq", "amp", source=source1, size=10)
line = fig2.line("x", "y", source=source2)

def callback(source1=source1, source2=source2):
    indices = cb_data.index["1d"].indices
    if len(indices) > 0:
        i = indices[0]
        f = source1.data.freq[i]
        a = source1.data.amp[i]
        for j in range(len(source2.data.x)):
            source2.data.y[j] = a * Math.sin(f * source2.data.x[j])
        source2.change.emit()

hover = HoverTool(callback=CustomJS.from_py_func(callback))
fig1.add_tools(hover)

show(column(fig1, fig2))
```

Comment: Please note that there is a recent new syntax for accessing selections that should be preferred in new code going forward: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/releases/0.12.15.html#selections

Comment: Can python variables be used in the callback function to replace the values in source2?

Comment: Also, if I want the callback to be called on a certain source, how would I implement that? Usually `callback = source1.callback`could be used, but that would clash would the python function wouldn't it?